# How to detect when bot was added to conversation and other events?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am testing a bot that I am building using the Bot Framework. The emulator for local testing that Microsoft created has several *events* that can be provided to the bot to solicit a response.

I looked at the GitHub samples provided for Node.js [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/Node/examples), but I can not find any example that responds to the different *events* within the Bot Framework Emulator.

The states are:

1. Bot Added to Conversation
2. Bot Removed from Conversation
3. User Added to Conversation
4. User Removed from Conversation
5. End of Conversation
6. Ping
7. Delete User Data

The [API](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/nodejs/modules/_botbuilder_d_.html) also does not make it clear how to achieve any of these actions.

Does anyone have any insight on where I should be looking for a example, or the API entries that I should be using?

In response to one of the answers, I did try code -

`.onDefault(function (session) { console.log(session.message.type); }`

But it only ever display "message" if a message was sent by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Node SDK, the botConnectorBot is able to trigger custom listeners on events using the `on()` handler.

**Example**

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var bot = new builder.BotConnectorBot({ appId: 'APPID', appSecret: 'APPSECRET' });
bot.on('DeleteUserData', function(message) {
    // Handle Deleting User Data
});
```

More information can be found [here](http://docs.botframework.com/builder/node/bots/BotConnectorBot/#connector-message-types).

You are also able to configure some standard messages using the `configure()` method.

**Example**

```
bot.configure({
    userWelcomeMessage: "Hello... Welcome to the group.",
    goodbyeMessage: "Goodbye..."
});
```

More information on what can be configured through options is located [here](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/nodejs/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.ibotconnectoroptions.html).

**Concerns**

This is not part of the question, as the question was to identify how to listen to these events. But as a general concern, the event listener does not return a session object. It is unclear how to *act* once you handle the event.

Answer (score 1):

The incoming message.type field will have "BotAddedToConversation" etc.

Comment: I did see the message.type field.

When I output the message.type it only displays in the console when I send a message (with type message). Using User Added to Conversation does not trigger the onDefault, and I don't output the message type. 

`.onDefault(function (session) { console.log(session.message.type); }`